# Android Backstack Examples?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-lifecycle, launchmode

Can any body tell me, what is the real life example of Intent Flags or launch mode. Please give me only real life use of these flags not an example like Activity A call Activity B using standard intent. Give real Life example like:

In an eCommerce app, the user having access to the `make payment` screen once again after the payment has been successful.
In such cases, a way to redirect the user to return to the home screen is necessary. This is where android’s `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` intent flags come in handy.
The use case we consider today is where there are several activities A, B, C, D, E etc and the user navigates through these multiple times – A > B > C > D > E. After E, we need to return to B, but remove the whole activity stack so that only A and B remain.
this is real life use of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` + `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`.

At Which condition :

1. Only Single_Top Launch mode Or Single_Top Flag is best and its real life use ?
2. Only Single_task Launch Mode or New_task Flag is best and its use ?
3. Only Single_instance Launch Mode is best and its use ?
4. Only Clear_Top Flag is best and its use ?

Comment: +1. Interesting question, hope someone will help us :)